# How to calculate angles between hash of hashes elements

Tags: perl, hash

i have problem concerning hash of hashes reachability, which i cannot overcome, besides going through all elements using for and while cycles.
Hash of hashes is in this structure:

```
$atomsArray{$number} = {
      "x" => $x, 
      "y" => $y,
      "z" => $z
};

for my $number(sort keys %atomsArray){
   while ((my $key, my $value) = each(%{$atomsArray{$number}})){
       #Counting angles between atoms(x,y,z)
   }
```

Is there any better way than this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a hash slice is one option:

```
my ( $x, $y, $z ) = @{ $atomsArray{$number} }{ qw(x y z) };
```

Comment: or `$atomsArray{$number}{'x'}`, etc to get individual elements